# How can I minimize this code? because excel said it has more than 64 conditions

Tags: xlsx, xls, xlsm

note: those texts equivalent to $C$1 is a dropdown list.[image: see picture for reference]

```
=IF(
    $C$1="", "", IF(
        $C$1="AGLAYAN 1", T4, IF(
            $C$1="AGLAYAN 2", AI4, IF(
                $C$1="ALABEL", AX4, IF(
                    $C$1="BABAK 1",BM4,IF($C$1="BABAK 2",CB4,IF($C$1="BANAYBANAY",CQ4,IF($C$1="BANGA",DF4,IF($C$1="BANSALAN",DU4,IF($C$1="BANSALAN 2",EJ4,IF($C$1="BANSALAN 3",EY4,IF($C$1="BAROBO",FN4,IF($C$1="BATOBATO",GC4,IF($C$1="BAYUGAN",GR4,IF($C$1="BUHANGIN",HG4,IF($C$1="CALINAN",HV4,IF($C$1="CARMEN",IK4,IF($C$1="COMPOSTELA 1",IZ4,IF($C$1="COMPOSTELA 2",JO4,IF($C$1="CUGMAN",KD4,IF($C$1="DIGOS 1",KS4,IF($C$1="DIGOS 2",LH4,IF($C$1="DIGOS 3",LW4,IF($C$1="DON CARLOS 1",ML4,IF($C$1="ESPERANZA 1",NA4,IF($C$1="ESPERANZA 2",NP4,IF($C$1="ESPERANZA 3",OE4,IF($C$1="GENSAN",OT4,IF($C$1="HAGONOY",PI4,IF($C$1="HINATUAN",PX4,IF($C$1="ISULAN 1",QM4,IF($C$1="KABAKAN 1",RB4,IF($C$1="KABAKAN 2",RQ4,IF($C$1="KALILANGAN",SF4,IF($C$1="KAPALONG",SU4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 2",TJ4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 3",TY4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 4",UN4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 5",VC4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 6",VR4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 7",WG4,IF($C$1="KIDAPAWAN 8",WV4,IF($C$1="KRINKLES 1",XK4,IF($C$1="KRINKLES 2",XZ4,IF($C$1="LUPON 1",YO4,IF($C$1="LUPON 2",ZD4,IF($C$1="MAASIM",ZS4,IF($C$1="MAGPET",AAH4,IF($C$1="MAGSAYSAY",AAW4,IF($C$1="MAITUM",ABL4,IF($C$1="MAKILALA",ACA4,IF($C$1="MALAYBALAY",ACP4,IF($C$1="MALITA",ADE4,IF($C$1="MANGAGOY",ADT4,IF($C$1="MARAMAG 1",AEI4,IF($C$1="MARAMAG 2",AEX4,IF($C$1="MARBEL 1",AFM4,IF($C$1="MARBEL 2",AGB4,IF($C$1="MARIKIT",AGQ4,IF($C$1="MATALAM",AHF4,IF($C$1="MATANAO",AHU4,IF($C$1="MIDSAYAP",AIJ4,IF($C$1="MLANG",AIY4,IF($C$1="MONKAYO",AJN4,IF($C$1="NABUNTURAN 1",AKC4,IF($C$1="NABUNTURAN 2",AKR4,IF($C$1="NABUNTURAN 3",AKG4,IF($C$1="OZAMIZ",ALV4,IF($C$1="PADADA",AMK4,IF($C$1="PANABO 2",AMZ4,IF($C$1="PANABO 3",ANO4,IF($C$1="PANABO 5",AOD4,IF($C$1="PANABO MAIN",AOS4,IF($C$1="PANABO PDP 1",APH4,IF($C$1="PANABO PDP 2",APW4,IF($C$1="PANTUKAN",AQL4,IF($C$1="PEÑAPLATA",ARA4,IF($C$1="PIGKAWAYAN",ARP4,IF($C$1="POLOMOLOK 1",ASE4,IF($C$1="POLOMOLOK 2",AST4,IF($C$1="PUERTO",ATI4,IF($C$1="QUEZON",ATX4,IF($C$1="SAN FRANCISCO 1",AUM4,IF($C$1="STA. MARIA",AVB4,IF($C$1="STO NIÑO",AVQ4,IF($C$1="STO. TOMAS",AWF4,IF($C$1="SULOP",AWU4,IF($C$1="SURIGAO 2",AXJ4,IF($C$1="TACORONG 1",AXY4,IF($C$1="TACORONG 2",AYN4,IF($C$1="TAGBINA",AZC4,IF($C$1="TAGUM 4",AZR4,IF($C$1="TIBUNGCO 1",BAG4,IF($C$1="TIBUNGCO 2",BAV4,IF($C$1="TORIL 1",BBK4,IF($C$1="TORIL 2",BBZ4,IF($C$1="TRENTO",BCO4,IF($C$1="TULUNAN",BDD4,IF($C$1="TUPI",BDS4,""))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You could possible write a VBA script

Comment: i don't have any background yet on VBA Programming

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my revised Answer yet?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following...

First, bring up the Worksheet_Change event's VBA code.  To do this click somewhere in your woeksheet.  Choose the `Developer` menu.  Choose `Design Mode`.  Choose `View Code`.

Next, paste in the following code...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
        Select Case $C$1
            Case "AGLAYAN 1"
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "T4:AH19" ).Value
            Case "AGLAYAN 2"
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AI4:AW19" ).Value
            Case "ALABEL",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AX4:BL19" ).Value
            Case "BABAK 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BM4:CA19" ).Value
            Case "BABAK 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "CB4:CP19" ).Value
            Case "BANAYBANAY",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "CQ4:DE19" ).Value
            Case "BANGA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "DF4:DT19" ).Value
            Case "BANSALAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "DU4:EI19" ).Value
            Case "BANSALAN 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "EJ4:EX19" ).Value
            Case "BANSALAN 3",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "EY4:FM19" ).Value
            Case "BAROBO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "FN4:GB19" ).Value
            Case "BATOBATO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "GC4:GQ19" ).Value
            Case "BAYUGAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "GR4:HF19" ).Value
            Case "BUHANGIN", HG4,
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "HG4:HU19" ).Value
            Case "CALINAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "HV4:IJ19" ).Value
            Case "CARMEN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "IK4:IY19" ).Value
            Case "COMPOSTELA 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "IZ4:JN19" ).Value
            Case "COMPOSTELA 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "JO4:KC19" ).Value
            Case "CUGMAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "KD4:KR19" ).Value
            Case "DIGOS 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "KS4:LG19" ).Value
            Case "DIGOS 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "LH4:LV19" ).Value
            Case "DIGOS 3",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "LW4:MK19" ).Value
            Case "DON CARLOS 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ML4:MZ19" ).Value
            Case "ESPERANZA 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "NA4:NO19" ).Value
            Case "ESPERANZA 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "NP4:OD19" ).Value
            Case "ESPERANZA 3",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "OE4:OS19" ).Value
            Case "GENSAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "OT4:PH19" ).Value
            Case "HAGONOY",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "PI4:PW19" ).Value
            Case "HINATUAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "PX4:QL19" ).Value
            Case "ISULAN 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "QM4:RA19" ).Value
            Case "KABAKAN 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "RB4:RP19" ).Value
            Case "KABAKAN 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "RQ4:SE19" ).Value
            Case "KALILANGAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "SF4:ST19" ).Value
            Case "KAPALONG",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "SU4:TI19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "TJ4:TX19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 3",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "TY4:UM19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 4",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "UN4:VB19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 5",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "VC4:VQ19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 6",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "VR4:WF19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 7",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "WG4:WU19" ).Value
            Case "KIDAPAWAN 8",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "WV4:XJ19" ).Value
            Case "KRINKLES 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "XK4:XY19" ).Value
            Case "KRINKLES 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "XZ4:YN19" ).Value
            Case "LUPON 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "YO4:ZC19" ).Value
            Case "LUPON 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ZD4:ZR19" ).Value
            Case "MAASIM",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ZS4:AAG19" ).Value
            Case "MAGPET",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AAH4:AAV19" ).Value
            Case "MAGSAYSAY",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AAW4:ABK19" ).Value
            Case "MAITUM",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ABL4:ABZ19" ).Value
            Case "MAKILALA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ACA4:ACO19" ).Value
            Case "MALAYBALAY",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ACP4:ADD19" ).Value
            Case "MALITA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ADE4:ADS19" ).Value
            Case "MANGAGOY",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ADT4:AEH19" ).Value
            Case "MARAMAG 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AEI4:AEW19" ).Value
            Case "MARAMAG 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AEX4:AFL19" ).Value
            Case "MARBEL 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AFM4:AGA19" ).Value
            Case "MARBEL 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AGB4:AGP19" ).Value
            Case "MARIKIT",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AGQ4:AHE19" ).Value
            Case "MATALAM",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AHF4:AHT19" ).Value
            Case "MATANAO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AHU4:AII19" ).Value
            Case "MIDSAYAP",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AIJ4:AIX19" ).Value
            Case "MLANG",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AIY4:AJM19" ).Value
            Case "MONKAYO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AJN4:AKB19" ).Value
            Case "NABUNTURAN 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AKC4:AKQ19" ).Value
            Case "NABUNTURAN 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AKR4:ALF19" ).Value
            Case "NABUNTURAN 3",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ALG4:ALU19" ).Value
            Case "OZAMIZ",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ALV4:AMJ19" ).Value
            Case "PADADA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AMK4:AMY19" ).Value
            Case "PANABO 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AMZ4:ANNP19" ).Value
            Case "PANABO 3",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ANO4:AOC19" ).Value
            Case "PANABO 5",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AOD4:AOR19" ).Value
            Case "PANABO MAIN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AOS4:APG19" ).Value
            Case "PANABO PDP 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "APH4:APV19" ).Value
            Case "PANABO PDP 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "APW4:AQK19" ).Value
            Case "PANTUKAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AQL4:AQZ19" ).Value
            Case "PEÑAPLATA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ARA4:ARO19" ).Value
            Case "PIGKAWAYAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ARP4:ASD19" ).Value
            Case "POLOMOLOK 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ASE4:ASS19" ).Value
            Case "POLOMOLOK 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AST4:ATH19" ).Value
            Case "PUERTO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ATI4:ATW19" ).Value
            Case "QUEZON",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "ATX4:AUL19" ).Value
            Case "SAN FRANCISCO 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AUM4:AVA19" ).Value
            Case "STA. MARIA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AVB4:AVP19" ).Value
            Case "STO NIÑO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AVQ4:AWE19" ).Value
            Case "STO. TOMAS",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AWF4:AWT19" ).Value
            Case "SULOP",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AWU4:AXI19" ).Value
            Case "SURIGAO 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AXJ4:AXX19" ).Value
            Case "TACORONG 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AXY4:AYM19" ).Value
            Case "TACORONG 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AYN4:AZB19" ).Value
            Case "TAGBINA",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AZC4:AZQ19" ).Value
            Case "TAGUM 4",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "AZR4:BAF19" ).Value
            Case "TIBUNGCO 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BAG4:BAU19" ).Value
            Case "TIBUNGCO 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BAV4:BBJ19" ).Value
            Case "TORIL 1",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BBK4:BBY19" ).Value
            Case "TORIL 2",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BBZ4:BCN19" ).Value
            Case "TRENTO",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BCO4:BDC19" ).Value
            Case "TULUNAN",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BDD4:BDR19" ).Value
            Case "TUPI",
                Range( "E4:S19" ).Value = Range( "BDS4:BEG19" ).Value
            Case Else
                Range( "E4" ).Value = "Error encountered"
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, choose `Close and Return to Microsoft Excel` from the `File` menu.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: thanks but when i try your code there is an invalid name error and the code seems not working

Comment: I'll just finish updating my answer, then hunt that error down.

Comment: still not working. i just simply want to display my encoded data to another cell for easy viewing if it meets the condition. thank you very much.

Comment: I'll keep looking.

Comment: can you make a VBA for this problem?

Comment: I believe so.  Do you wish me to try?

Comment: I still can't find anything wrong with my syntax.  What is the exact wording of the error message that you receive?

Comment: please be informed that $C$1 is a dropdown list, if $C$1="AGLAYAN 1" E4 will be having the value of T4 so on and so forth

Comment: Where are the values used to populate the drop-down stored?

Comment: on the other sheet

Comment: In what cell are you placing the formula?

Comment: it's on cell E4

Comment: Are you still receiving an error message?  If so, then what is it?  Is any data placed in the Cell?  If `AGLAYAN 1` is chosen, is there any value in `T4` to display?

Comment: yes i put value on T4 but on cell E4 there is a #NAME error

Comment: i use this VBA code and it worked. Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Range("C1").Value = "AGLAYAN 1" Then Range("E4:S19").Value = Range("T4:AH19").Value
End Sub

Comment: No it's the command button I've inserted. I wonder if I can automatically view the data from T4 to E4 without clicking or using a command button

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can.  I'm working on some code that should fill `E4` (and the rest) automatically.

Comment: Without using VBA? That would be nice.

Comment: Using some VBA, though it is not much more advanced than what you have above.  It might be possible with a command button and a formula - I would have to research that some more, though.

Comment: I have also found a site but I'm so confused how to make it. I think this can help. https://trumpexcel.com/extract-data-from-drop-down-list/

Comment: Now I figured it out, my excel doesn't support SWITCH function. But I am using Excel 2016 already I am wondering why it is not working.

Comment: have to go afk for about 40 minutes or so.